# how to disable log warning of a class (pynput) in python (on macos)

Tags: python, logging, warnings, pynput

I'm using pynput.mouse to capture the action click:

```
from pynput import mouse
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print('{0} at {1}'.format('Pressed' if pressed else 'Released',(x, y)))
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False
with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

always receiving this warning

> [ WARNING] darwin.py:191 - This process is not trusted! Input event
> monitoring will not be possible until it is added to accessibility
> clients.

source code at line 191 https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/blob/master/lib/pynput/_util/darwin.py

after giving permission to the IDE in the system setting, the warning is gone, but can I hide/disable the warning in the code like `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")`? Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

Go System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility, then add PyCharm to the list of accessibility clients.

Comment: I ran it on Mac and got the message, thanks anyway

Comment: @ybbb did you try it?

Comment: I add the pycharm to the list of accessibility clients and the warning is gone, thanks a lot! Still I'm wondering whether there how to omit this level of  warning in the code like warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")?